# How to make commands recognize in cygwin when installed from some other installer?

Tags: ruby, windows, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, cygwin

I just installed Ruby on rails on windows using a installer. I go to cmd.exe and run `rails` or `ruby`, `gem` it works but when I do the same when I go to cygwin, it says:

```
$ rails
-bash: /usr/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: Permission denied

$ gem
-bash: /usr/bin/gem: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

This is wierd but I dont know how will I connect both of them? This happened also with `heroku` command.

```
$ heroku
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku: line 4: /cygdrive/c/Program Fi/ruby: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku: line 4: exec: /cygdrive/c/Prog/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Its true that `rails, ruby, gem` are not cygwin packages to be recognised. This is not just specific to ruby rails or gems but any new package that is not installed through cygwin. How can I make it recognise in cygwin.

Comment: How exactly did you install Ruby on Rails? It's not a standard Cygwin package, so I wouldn't expect Cygwin to be able to find a /usr/bin/rails.

Comment: good point. I installed through the installer online. but check my edit now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Installer + Cygwin: How to best use the ruby version of the rails installer inside Cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473837/rails-installer-cygwin-how-to-best-use-the-ruby-version-of-the-rails-installe)